# Leading principal minors VS Leading minors

Tags: matrices, terminology, determinant, education

Are "leading principal minors" and "leading minors" the same thing? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: *Principal minor* is when you delete $k$ rows, and $k$ columns of the same indexes. *Leading principal minor* is when both sets are the last $k$ of each kind.

Comment: Hello @Boxwood my question is different; in both cases there is the word "leading".

Comment: *Leading minors* is either teaching or something illegal. They either forgot or shortened the name. *Leading principal minor* is too long to say.

Comment: @Boxwood here an example: https://www.google.it/books/edition/Completely_Positive_Matrices/AllToPtYGGgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22leading+minors%22+of+a+matrix&pg=PA50&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Yes, they are using [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)